# SQL server select max two dates from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know how if it is possible to select the two most recent dates from a column in a table. Please see the simple example below. I know to get the max date I can use the max function. I'm also aware that I could then do another max statement with a where condition that states it must be less than the first date returned from my first max query. I was wondering though if there was a way of doing this in one query?

```
Name     DateAdded
ABC      2014-04-20
ABC      2014-04-20
ABC      2014-03-01
ABC      2014-03-01
ABC      2014-02-25
ABC      2014-05-22
ABC      2014-04-01
```

The two dates that should be returned are the two most recent, i.e. 2014-05-22 & 2014-04-20.

**EDIT**

Sorry I should have mentioned yes I want two distnict dates. The table is large and the dates are not sorted. I think sorting the table could be quite slow.

Comment: Would you like to return distinct values ? if you had 2 records with `2014-05-22` would you return 2 times this, or `2014-05-22` and `2014-04-20` ?

Comment: @Bartdude yes I've just edited my question after seeing your comment. I should have said I would like two distinct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct top 2 Dateadded 
FROM table 
ORDER BY Dateadded desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top(2) DateAdded
from table
order by DateAdded DESC
```

Comment: if I had say 3 dates of 2014-05-22 would that not just return me 2014-05-22 twice? I will also edit my question as I forgot to say to mention its a large table and sorting it might be quite slow

Comment: With an index on DateAdded column it won't be any slower with large table. To get only distinct dates use the `distinct` or `group by DateAdded`

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
select distinct top(2) format(Dateadded ,'yyyy-MM-dd') as Dateadded 
from TableName
order by Dateadded DESC
```